# Celery - how to stop running task when using distributed RabbitMQ backend?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

If I am running Celery on (say) a bank of 50 machines all using a distributed RabbitMQ cluster.

If I have a task that is running and I know the task id, how in the world can Celery figure out which machine its running on to terminate it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can actually do it, when you spawn a task you will have a worker, somewhere in you 50 boxes, that executes that and you technically have no control on it as it s a separate process and the only thing you can control is either the asyncResult or the amqp message on the queue.